# From where I should learn about htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm working in PHP but didn't know about htaccess. And these days I know how much the value of htaccess. So, I decide to learn first htacces then step forward. But don't know from where I should start? Please provide your guidelines. I want to learn complete tips & tricks about htaccess. I know something but I want to learn more techniques. Like I want to create SEO friendly url and other category url's. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these links :

A tutorial for beginers
**Tutorial for mod-rewrite beginners**
https://amitoverflow.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

**.htaccess file)**

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

URL rewriting Tutorial

**URL Rewriting)**

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

**Apache official Documentation)**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: You really told something from where I got a lot of new things. Such a great site to understand things. Easy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should check
http://htaccess-guide.com/
It is pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Official How-To / Tutorials are located here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

But there are plenty of resources out there in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing is, you should avoid using `.htaccess` if possible. It's not about using `.htaccess` to get what you need it's about using the Apache directives. If you have access to Apache config or vhost that is much better as any directive can be used there. Please start with when not to use `.htaccess` directly from Apache at the link below.

[When not to use .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Using `.htaccess` gives a small performance hit on the server for every request because it scans every directory looking for this file to apply any directives. 
Most big sites don't use .htaccess, they put it in the config or vhost file and leaves it with `AllowOverride None`.

Now one of the most important things you will need to know is `mod_rewrite`. `Mod_rewrite` uses Regex for most of it's pattern matching.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

This site is helpful in understanding regex because it is quite complicated at first and still can be even with experience.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

You will also probably want to look over what can be done with Apache in general versus how to use just `.htaccess`.

Learning the core features will help you a lot and it tell you which features can be used with `.htaccess` or only Config

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html